# Not able to connect Azure Cache for Redis in Private Subnet

Tags: c#, azure, stackexchange.redis

We are trying to connect to Azure Cache for Redis using C# code. Its returns NULL object.

This started happing after we converting our public subnet to private subnet.

```
private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
{
    var redisConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RedisCacheCnStr"].ConnectionString;
    return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConnectionString);
});

public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection { get { return lazyConnection.Value; } }
```

We checked logs we are getting object reference error as connected object is Null.

Comment: What is the framework you are using? Please share your `Configuration` file once.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below steps to connect `Azure Cache for Redis in Private Subnet`.

- First create a `Virtual Network`.

[image]

- Create a  `Subnet` with the Virtual Network.
- Initially you will have a `default` subnet. Create one more with your `NSG`.
- Make sure you have selected the `NSG`.

[image]

***Create Azure Cache for Redis***

[image]

[image]

- There is no change in the code which you are trying to connect.

```cs
 string cacheConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CacheConnection"].ConnectionString;
 connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(cacheConnection);
```

[image]

- Just update the connection string with the IP address.

In `web.config`,add the connection string.

```cs
 <connectionStrings>   
    <add name="CacheConnection" connectionString="IPAddress:PortNo,password=redis-cache-key,abortConnect=False" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Get the `IPAddress` from `Virtual Network` in Azure Cache for Redis.
[image]